# How to access local storage from chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have a web application that I'm writing a chrome extension for, and in this web application I save data to local storage. I am trying to access this data from a chrome extension, but none of these options are able to access the local storage that isn't associated with just the scope of the extension:

```
localStorage.getItem
localStorage["itemName"]
chrome.storage.local.get function
chrome.storage.sync.get function
```

None of these methods have worked, as they all return "null" or "undefined" for items that I know exist in the localStorage that have been set from my web application. Can someone please help? I thought this would be a simple task but so far I can't solve it.

Comment: is this code in background or content script?

Comment: It's in the background, I think, I only have 1 js file so I don't think I have any content scripts. Would this work if I was using a content script?

Comment: yes, content script would work better

Comment: HTML5 localStorage is per URL origin so you need a content script to access it, then use messaging to communicate with the background script.

Comment: Got it; I just added a content script and I'm now able to do what I need to be able to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Jaromanda X and wOxxOm have kindly pointed out, using a content script gives me the access I need to solve this--thanks!